# Setting up a VM to use a different IP range than vSphere/ESXI host

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, subnet

I currently have a server that is running vSphere 5 (ESXi). My management interface (VMKernel) has an address of 173.198.215.78 and the gateway on that one is 173.198.215.78. It appears to be set up fine and I can manage the server over that IP.

The problem comes when I set up VMs on the same vSwitch. It's pretty much a default configuration. My host has given me a small block of IPs from another subnet and I'm trying to utilize them in my VM, with no luck:

IP 173.198.246.72
Netmask 255.255.255.255
Gateway 173.198.215.77

My host told me to set the gateway to 173.198.215.78. Is that correct? Either way, when I add those settings to my Windows Server 2008 VM, it cannot route out to the Internet.

If someone could point me towards where I am going wrong, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you sure the VMKernel gateway is configured to the VMKernel port address?  That shouldn't work -- can you confirm those settings, and check what the netmask is set to?

Comment: That isn't a small block of IP's - it's a single IP.  Can you confirm the netmask with your provider - specifically that it isn't 173.198.246.72 with a mask of 255.255.255.248?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mistyped that.  Thank you for catching it.  The VMKernel IP is 173.198.215.78 and the gateway is .77.  The netmask is 255.255.255.252.  My block of IPs is 173.198.246.72-79.  My provider says that they were added to the switchport my server is on.  They told me to utilize netmask of 255.255.255.255.

Comment: Is it a problem that my default gateway to the Internet is on a different subnet?

Comment: 255.255.255.252 is a /30, or 4 addresses (173.198.215.76/30), which would make sense if you vmkernel were .78 and the router was .77.  My guess is that your mask actually should be a /29 (8 hosts), which is 255.255.255.248.  I would confirm this, but if this is the case then you should try numbering your vhost at 173.198.215.73 with a mask of 255.255.255.248 and a gateway of 173.198.215.77.